# What is the time complexity of a, b = b, a in Python where a and b are both lists?

Tags: python, list

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [5,6,7,8,9]
```

Can you tell me what the time complexity of:

```
a, b = b, a
```

will be?

I am guessing O(n+m) where n and m are the length of respective lists.

Comment: The contents of the lists are not involved; you're just swapping two variables. It's O(1).

Comment: This is constant time, the types involved are **completely irrelevant**, assignment is always constant time.

Answer (score 6):

It is O(1) because Python is just changing the names assigned to list objects, not actually touching the data in the lists.